# How to put my code in the do while loop?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to check this condition for the whole page in word.

```
If Options.CheckGrammarWithSpelling = True Then
    Selection.Comments.Add Range:=Selection.Range
    Selection.TypeText Text:="WRONG!!!"
    'ActiveDocument.CheckGrammar
Else
    'ActiveDocument.CheckSpelling
    'Selection.Comments.Add Range:=Selection.Range
End If
```

Comment: Bad code formatting, and I see no `do while` construction. You should tell more and give more code, and *format* it properly. Your question is unclear.

Comment: can u pls add the do while in that snippet itself...

Comment: What did you try? Do you know the syntax of `do while` loops in VBA? Read more about them! What is your program trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a Do While Loop. Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub DoSpellCheckAndComment()
    Dim oWord As Range
    Dim StoryRange As Range

    For Each StoryRange In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
        Application.CheckSpelling Word:=StoryRange
        For Each oWord In StoryRange.Words
            If Not Application.CheckSpelling(Word:=oWord.Text) Then
                oWord.Select
                oWord.Comments.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Text:="WRONG!!!"
            End If
        Next oWord
    Next StoryRange
End Sub
```